# how to use "consistency" parameter in java api when put data to elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have used "consistency" parameter in python program to put data to elasticsearch  successfully ,but i can not find a usage of "consistency" in java api. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
 client.prepareIndex("index", "doc", "doc1")
                .setSource("doc")
                .setConsistencyLevel(WriteConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
                .execute()
                .actionGet()
```

---

Comment: **Thank you very much.**

It seems like you code can work well in elasticsearch 1.5.x .


I have forgot tell you my elasticsearch version 2.3.2, so my code like below :


`Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "my_clustername").put("index.number_of_replicas", 0).put("index.number_of_shards", 30).build();

 Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.3.5"), 9300));`

Comment: Your code is ok. But my code works well with ES 2.3.2. I tried and nothing seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Read below links :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking_50_java_api_changes.html#_writeconsistencylevel_removed_on_write_requests

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-index_.html#index-wait-for-active-shards

I think you can use setWaitForActiveShards, which can take a numerical value up to the total number of shard copies or ActiveShardCount.ALL for all shard copies.